# What is the most reliable way to fetching the scroped CSS attribute in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In vuejs the elements are assigned an attribute starting 'data-v-***'

I could not find any docs about fetching this value so ended up using refs and grabbing the attributes of the main node:

```
<template>
  <div class="m-colour-picker" ref="thisContainer">
  ...
  </div>
</template>
```

```
    const attributes = this.$refs.thisContainer.getAttributeNames();
    let dataAttribute = '';
    attributes.forEach((attribute: string) => {
      if (attribute.substring(0, 5) === 'data-') {
        dataAttribute = attribute;
      }
    });
```

But it feels a little forced.. is there a method in vue to fetch this already built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has little to do with Vue.js. Data attributes for any element are automatically synced with it's internal [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) object.

Example:

```js
console.log(foobar.dataset);

console.log(foobar.dataset.vFoo);
console.log(foobar.dataset.vBar);

// notice how data attributes containing more than the initial data- dash
// are automatically transformed to camel case:
// data-v-foo-bar ===> dataset.vFooBar
console.log(foobar.dataset.vFooBar);

// if all you care about is the names of the attributes:
console.log(Object.keys(foobar.dataset));
```

```html
<div id="foobar" data-v-foo="bar" data-v-bar="baz" data-v-foo-bar="foobaz"></div>
```

Comment: Ref for those `data-*` attributes : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset

Comment: new day new trick :) thanks i had no idea about this